# foreachの使い方

Tags: php

foreach($test as $key => $value) {}
foreach($test as $value) {}

上記の使い分けはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

配列の反復処理をする際に要素のキーを利用した処理をするかどうかによります。

■要素のキーを利用する場合は

```
foreach($test as $key => $value) {}
```

$keyには各反復で現在の要素のキーが代入されます。
$valueには各反復において現在の要素の値が代入されます。

■要素のキーを利用しない場合は

```
foreach($test as $value) {}
```

$valueには各反復において現在の要素の値が代入されます。